# Docker Compose with Rails hanging up on command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm following the Docker Rails tutorial via https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#build-the-project (using Windows 10 Home)

EDIT: Just a note, I am using **docker-toolbox** because Docker requires Windows 10 Pro for Hyper-V, and I have Windows 10 Home edition.

I have gone through the tutorial several times, and each time I run docker-compose up, it gets hung up and doesn't mention the local port the app is running on. I have also tried making a new app and changing the port number in docker-compose.yml to see if that would fix the issue.

All of the previous commands in the tutorial have worked properly, and I have edited the config/database.yml file correctly, before running the docker-compose up command.

I have deleted images, and all files and started from scratch several times. I still run into the same issue.

Here are the commands from the tutorial:

```
docker-compose run web rails new . --force --database=postgresql --skip-bundle

docker-compose build

docker-compose up

docker-compose run web rails db:create
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev    nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp
```

Here is the output from docker-compose up:

```
$ docker-compose up
mydockerbuild_db_1 is up-to-date
Creating mydockerbuild_web_1
Attaching to mydockerbuild_db_1, mydockerbuild_web_1
db_1   | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user            "postgres".
db_1   | This user must also own the server process.
db_1   |
db_1   | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1   | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1   | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1   |
db_1   | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1   |
db_1   | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data     ... ok
db_1   | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1   | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1   | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1   | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1   | creating configuration files ... ok
db_1   | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1   | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1   |
db_1   | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1   | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A,   or
db_1   | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1   | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1   |
db_1   | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1   |
db_1   |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1   |
db_1   | ****************************************************
db_1   | WARNING: No password has been set for the database.
db_1   |          This will allow anyone with access to the
db_1   |          Postgres port to access your database. In
db_1   |          Docker's default configuration, this is
db_1   |          effectively any other container on the same
db_1   |          system.
db_1   |
db_1   |          Use "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set
db_1   |          it in "docker run".
db_1   | ****************************************************
db_1   | waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down    at 2017-02-14 18:56:05 UTC
db_1   | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1   | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1   | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server started
db_1   | ALTER ROLE
db_1   |
db_1   |
db_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-  initdb.d/*
db_1   |
db_1   | LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1   | LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db_1   | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1   | LOG:  shutting down
db_1   | waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  database system is shut  down
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server stopped
db_1   |
db_1   | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1   |
db_1   | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-02-14 18:56:06 UTC
db_1   | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1   | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1   | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1   | LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1   | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1   | LOG:  shutting down
db_1   | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1   | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-02-14 19:06:12 UTC
db_1   | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1   | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1   | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1   | ERROR:  database "myapp_development" already exists
db_1   | STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "myapp_development" ENCODING =   'unicode'
db_1   | ERROR:  database "myapp_test" already exists
db_1   | STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "myapp_test" ENCODING = 'unicode'
db_1   | ERROR:  database "myapp_development" already exists
db_1   | STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "myapp_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'
db_1   | ERROR:  database "myapp_test" already exists
db_1   | STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "myapp_test" ENCODING = 'unicode'
db_1   | ERROR:  database "myapp_development" already exists
db_1   | STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "myapp_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'
db_1   | ERROR:  database "myapp_test" already exists
db_1   | STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "myapp_test" ENCODING = 'unicode'
```

Comment: Are the log files different if you docker-compose down, then back up?   it looks like this log is attaching to an already running container.

Comment: I just tried this and the log files don't give errors at the end about the database pre-existing. However, it still doesn't mention being able to run locally at port 3000, and I get a "this site can't be reached" when I try localhost:3000.

Comment: Your logs show database activity, but no activity for the web app -- that's why I asked.  Can't troubleshoot if you can't see.  ;)

Comment: That's part of the problem actually. I don't get any web logs. The database activity is all that comes up. What I displayed above is everything that is outputted.

Comment: Maybe postgress isn't starting correctly.   Try removing depends_on and see if it starts.  If it does, then your postgress is blocking your web app.